# Get data in current date last hour in sql

Tags: mysql, date, datetime, group-by, hour

i want to count the data in current date last hour (for example now() is  2020-04-11 12:30:00 , then i want to get data before 12. any idea ?

table_a

```
timestamp           
2020-04-11 10:00:00     
2020-04-11 10:00:00     
2020-04-11 11:00:00     
2020-04-11 12:00:00  
2020-04-11 12:30:00
```

expected results:

```
timestamp            count
2020-04-11 10:00:00     2
2020-04-11 11:00:00     1
2020-04-11 12:00:00     1
```

i'm using mysql 8

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: i'm using mysql 8

Answer (score 1):

Based on other questions, it seems like you are using MySQL.  So, one method is:

```
where timestamp >= curdate() and
      hour(timestamp) < hour(now())
```

Comment: why the output was empty ?

Comment: I fixed the query.  That should be `hour(now())`, not `hour(curdate())`.

Comment: thank u, its works for me! can u upvote my questions ?

Comment: @hinafaya Nope. It doesn't work like that.

Comment: its work for me with little different query, `   where date(timestamp) >= date(now()) and hour(timestamp) < hour(now()) 
    group by hour(timestamp)`

Comment: @10Rep u can upvote my questions if its clear

Comment: @hinafaya But you cannot ask that. I don't really think it's clear. I didnt downvote your question, but I didn't upvote either. On the other hand, if Gordon's answer helped you, then please upvote it. Accept the answer you think helped you the most.

Answer (score 1):

Like Gordon mentioned you need to go with the where clause however looking at your table:

```
SELECT timestamp, COUNT(*)
FROM table_a
WHERE timestamp >= curdate() and
      hour(timestamp) < hour(now())
Group by timestamp
```

Should be the complete query.....

Comment: its also works for me, thankss! can u upvote my questions ?

Comment: @hinafaya if it works can you accept it, so future readers know that the question has been solved??